# How to access nodes when your component is passed to connect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs

I'm trying to access the MetaDetails component in the test case but unable to do so since its wrapped with the Provider. The goal is to access the PrintLabelButton component on click of which I need to mock 'handlePrintLabelButtonClick' function.

**Utils.js**

```
export const handlePrintLabelButtonClick = (
  e,
  rmaNumber,
  labelUrl,
  getReturnLabel
) => {
  const rmaList = [];

  e.preventDefault();
  if (!labelUrl) {
    const container = { rmaNo: "" };
    container.rmaNo = rmaNumber;
    rmaList.push(container);
    getReturnLabel(rmaList);
  } else {
    window.open(labelUrl, "_blank");
  }
};
```

**Page.js**

```
import {
  filterReturnLabelResponse,
  handlePrintLabelButtonClick
} from "../../utils/common-util";



import { PrintLabelButton } from "./printLabel";

Const MetaDetails = () => {
    //a lot of code 
{showPrintLabelButton && (
                        <PrintLabelButton
                          onClickHandle={e =>
                            handlePrintLabelButtonClick(
                              e,
                              rmaNumber,
                              labelUrl,
                              getReturnLabel
                            )
                          }
                          url={labelUrl}
                          target="_blank"
                          type="printLabel"
                          text={intl.formatMessage(messages.printLabelText)}
                          
                        />
                      )}
// again a lot of code 
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  // some code
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  // some code
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(injectIntl(MetaDetails));
```

**PrintLabelButton.js**

```
export const PrintLabelButton = ({
  target,
  url,
  type,
  text,
  onClickHandle
}: PrintLabelButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <ButtonWrapper>
      <AnchorWrapper
        href={url}
        target={target}
        type={type}
        
      >
        <DefaultButton
          tabIndex="0"
          onClick={onClickHandle}
          data-test="print-label-button"
        >
          {text}
        </DefaultButton>
      </AnchorWrapper>
    </ButtonWrapper>
  );
};
```

What I've tried so far

**MetaDetails.test.js**

```
test("Returns Component Whats next button click", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MetaDetails/>
    </Provider>
  );
   
    const middle = wrapper.find(MetaDetails);
    const component = wrapper.find(`[data-test="print-label-button"]`).hostNodes();
    component.simulate("click");
    expect(mockSetModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Can someone please tell me how can I access nodes when your component is surrounded by the Provider.

Note: I am using react/@emotion

Comment: Why are you trying to unit test `PrintLabelButton` via another component? This isn't a unit test. I think you'll get the test coverage you want by unit testing `PrintLabelButton` and passing a mocked callback on the `onClickHandle` prop. Otherwise, you could just mock `handlePrintLabelButtonClick` that is used by `PrintLabelButton`.